# React why does my useEffect hook that retrieves local storage break after wrapping my state in context?

Tags: reactjs, json, local-storage, react-context

My working code before converting all my state into context:

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [reptile, setReptile] = useState(function () {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem("reptiles");
    return JSON.parse(storedValue);
  })...

...useEffect(
    function () {
      localStorage.setItem("reptiles", JSON.stringify(reptile));
    },
    [reptile]
  );
```

My current code:

**Context.js**

```
const ReptileContext = createContext();

function ReptileProvider({ children }) {
  const [reptile, setReptile] = useState(function () {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem("reptiles");
    return JSON.parse(storedValue);
  });

  const [daysFed, setDaysFed] = useState("");
  const [displayForm, setDisplayForm] = useState(false);
  const [displayList, setDisplayList] = useState(true);
  const [displayReptile, setDisplayReptile] = useState(false);
  const [selectedReptile, setSelectedReptile] = useState(null);
  const [today, setToday] = useState(null);
  const [reptileType, setReptileType] = useState("");
  const [reptileName, setReptileName] = useState("");
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState("");

  function handleAddReptile(reptile) {
    setReptile((reptiles) => [...reptiles, reptile]);
  }

  function handleDeleteReptile(reptileId) {
    setReptile((reptiles) => reptiles.filter((rep) => rep.id !== reptileId));
  }

  function handleSelection(reptileId) {
    setSelectedReptile(reptileId);
    setDisplayList(false);
    setDisplayReptile(true);
  }

  function handleBack() {
    setDisplayReptile(false);
    setDisplayList(true);
  }

  return (
    <ReptileContext.Provider
      value={
        (reptile,
        reptileType,
        setReptileType,
        reptileName,
        setReptileName,
        notes,
        setNotes,
        daysFed,
        setDaysFed,
        displayForm,
        setDisplayForm,
        displayList,
        setDisplayList,
        displayReptile,
        setDisplayReptile,
        selectedReptile,
        setSelectedReptile,
        today,
        setToday,
        handleAddReptile,
        handleDeleteReptile,
        handleSelection,
        handleBack)
      }
    >
      {children}
    </ReptileContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useReptile() {
  const context = useContext(ReptileContext);
  if (context === undefined)
    throw new Error("PostContext was used outside of the PostProvider");
  return context;
}

export { ReptileProvider, useReptile };
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const { displayForm, displayList, displayReptile, selectedReptile, reptile } =
    useReptile();

  useEffect(
    function () {
      if (!reptile) return;
      localStorage.setItem("reptiles", JSON.stringify(reptile));
    },
    [reptile]
  );
```

**index.js**

```
 <ReptileProvider>
      <App />
    </ReptileProvider>
```

I'm receiving an error upon load that reads "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". I believe the issue is directly related to where the useEffect hook is placed but I'm not entirely sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you share your whole provider and how do you include in your page?  Please include a complete example that reproduces the issue. I would expect that you use Context Provider and in the same component as you use your useContext hook. They need to be in different components. `<Provider><Component></Provider>` and Component can now use useContext hook.

Comment: @jcubic edited the post, they're in different components so I don't think that's the issue. I'm wondering if it's trying to fetch the reptile object from local storage when there is none? I tried adding a guard clause but that didn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not with the `useEffect` hook, but with the way you are passing the value to the `ReptileContext.Provider`. You are using parentheses instead of curly braces, which means you are passing a single expression instead of an object. This might cause the `JSON.parse` to fail when trying to read the stored value.

```
<ReptileContext.Provider value={{ ... }}></ReptileContext.Provider>
```

Comment: thank you! I'm still having some other issues but I think it's unrelated so I'm gonna mark this solved

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help. If you have any other issues, feel free to ask another question or follow up on this one. I hope you find a solution soon.